# Как фильтровать с помощью выпадающего списка

Tags: django, python-3.6

Только начал делать интрернет магазин в Django 2.0.3.
Создал заполнил немного товарами.

Есть 2 модели Brand и Item:

У Item есть  поле `brand` оно является ForeignKey от поля модели `Brand.name` (наименование бренда)

Каждый Item относится к разным Brand

Все настроил: На главной странице сайта есть два выпадающих списка один Brand а второй Item.

Когда пользователь выбирает какой-то Brand, то в выпадающем окошке он видит Item которые относятся ко всем Brand.

Как реализовать схему: Человек выбирает в первом окошке Brand, а во втором выпадающем списке будут видны Item только этого Brand ?

Answer (score 2):

Все довольно просто:

1. Вам нужна форма с полем ForeignKey, в котором юзер выбирает бренд и вторым полем, `ChoicesField`, на котором будет стоять readonly, данные к нему подтянем позже.
2. После того как юзер выбрал бренд, JavaScript c помощью Ajax должен подтянуть с сервера все айтемы с этим брендом (тут нужен простой API), потом обновить с новыми данными и разблокировать это поле в колбэке.

Если довольно сложно для вас, то можете реализовать в 2 страницы, на первой юзер выбирает бренд, отправляет запрос и уже на сервере вы в зависимости от выбранного бренда отправляйте ему айтемы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать двумя методами:

1) С помощью js отлавливать изменение списка Item, и подгружать в зависимости от выбранного Item список Brand

2) Использовать готовый механизм из [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light). Нужно обратить внимание на [использование вне админки](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-outside-the-admin) и [фильтрацию зависимых значений](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form).